# Can I abort a thunk from a dispatched action?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-thunk

At the beginning of the thunk I dispatch a 'START' action, then I await some async stuff, and finally dispatch a 'SUCCESS' action.

Sometimes it may happen that this thunk is dispatched again before the previous has ended (success action), so I want that the second START action is refused and the thunk stops continuing to the async stuff and END action.

So my approach is to check in middleware if a dispatched action has already been dispatched (previous action is the same as current), but I cant figure out how I could return from the thunk right after the refused action in a 'nice' way.

Currently I return false from the middleware and need to check the returned value from dispatch.

```
export const doSomething = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {

    if(!dispatch({type: 'START'})) return;

    //...async stuff

    dispatch({type: 'SUCCESS'});
}
```

Is there a way I could control this from one point (middleware)?

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is a reducer that change the store state according to those actions (`START`, `SUCCESS`,...).

If so , you have to check the store state before deciding the dispatch :

```
export const doSomething = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {

    if (getState().isLoading) return ; // <-- ⚠️ ⚠️ ⚠️

    if(!dispatch({type: 'START'})) return;

    //...async stuff

    dispatch({type: 'SUCCESS'});
}
```

assuming that the reducer did something like the following :

```
function (state = {}, action) {
  if (action.type === 'START') {
    return {...state , isLoading: true }; 
  }

  if (action.type === 'SUCCESS') {
    return {...state , isLoading: false }; 
  }
  return state;
}
```